# Failed to load keyboard when running Ionic app on phone for first time?

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework

It seems that my phone can nor access the keyboard.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
app.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined
```

I find this odd as I haven't added any keyboard functionality other than was included in the Blank template:

```
  angular.module('mymobile')
    .run(['$ionicPlatform',
      function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

          if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          }
          if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }
        });
      }]);
```

I googled and found an answer to this kind of topic that I should install `cordova-plugin-whitelist` but it was already installed as default. I also see that `ionic-plugin-keyboard` is installed.

I also added this meta tag to index.html per another recommendation:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

and this xml tag `<allow-navigation href="*"/>` just above `<access origin="*"/>` in config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The actions in the post together with reinstalling node.js, cordova, ionic and installing more Android SDK packages resolved the issue. I'm not sure which action(s) were decisive.